# Implement equals() for a Class with Cyclic Reference Java

Tags: java

I want a way to override the equals method for a class that has cyclic reference. Below is my class **EDIT:** Removed code for getters and setters

```
class Person implements Serializable{
    private String fullName;
    private Person friend;
    // Getters and setters

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Person other = (Person) obj;
        if (friend == null) {
            if (other.friend != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!friend.equals(other.friend))
            return false;
        if (fullName == null) {
            if (other.fullName != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!fullName.equals(other.fullName))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

And in the client class I have the following:

```
Person p1 = new Person();
Person p2 = new Person();
Person p3 = new Person();
p1.setFullName("nkuruza");
p2.setFullName("Another");
p3.setFullName("nkuruza");
p3.setFriend(p2);
p1.setFriend(p2);
p2.setFriend(p1);
```

The issue is calling the equals method in this situation, eg p1.equals(p3) produces StackOverflowException.

How can I implement my equals method without having to run into this issue?

I thank you in advance.

Comment: Why override equals() in the first place? Thde default implementation is probably the best one for such a class.

Comment: @JBNizet I tried that and the result is false when it should be true in the case for `p1.equals(p3)`

Comment: @Nkuruza How do you define equality for your `Person` objects with non-programming terms? When are two different `Person` objects supposed to be equal to each other?

Comment: @Progman that would be if the fullName is the same and friend(Person) is equal(by this definition) to other friend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The real answer is to model your classes along reality.

In reality, what are the *real* aspects that define a person?! 
That would be the identity, the name for example.

The *set* of your friends can change tomorrow, but you will still be you!

So, in other words: exclude the friends field from that comparison. Even better: consider not having this relationship written down as field within that class (and if at all, it should be a list, not a single instance). But as said, ideally, that information goes *outside* of the person class!

Answer (score 6):

Since `p1`'s `friend` is set to `p2`, and `p2`'s `friend` to `p1`, your `equals()` method ends up in an infinite call loop between the two `Person` instances:

`p1.equals(p2)` calls `p2.equals(p1)` calls `p1.equals(p2)` (forever - or rather until your JVM's currently configured stack size limit is reached, at which point it will throw a `StackOverflowException`)

A solution for now might be to directly test for unique attributes of the friend, (`fullname` is the only other attribute so far):

```
else if(!friend.fullName.equals(other.friend.fullName)
```

(...making sure to update the code to guard for any possible null values of course)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, this woud definitely solve my problem for cyclic reference but after reading @GhostCat's answer, I think my Model class is not along reality really and that's where the real problem is.

Comment: @Nkuruza upvote it too then ;) Also, I always appreciate it when the OP explains why it accepted another answer, it's good manners. Well done! :D

Comment: @tryman I upvoted both answers, but unfortunately I do not have enough reputation however StackOverflow assured me that the up votes were recoded :-)

Comment: Yw! Yes I agree wholeheartedly with @GhostCat and design is certainly the fundamental concern here. However I chose to focus on the mechanical issue you raised (the infinite "call loop") to help ensure you saw why it was happening in the first place.